# Customer render $scripts and $styles

Tags: theming

Short of replacing html.tpl.php and calling drupal_get_js/drupal_get_css functions and tweaking the output as required...

How else can I drop some of the JS or CSS that drupal (D7) seems to include in the resulting markup??

The ajaxPageState object is quite confusing I would rather start from minimal markup and stuff and build from what I know.

Any ideas/???

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I don't understand the title + question. Could you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about HTML markup or CSS/JS for the markup?

Comment: Basically all the CSS and JS (such a jQuery) needs to be removed...I will incrementally provide my own CSS implementations, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some alter hooks in your themes template file.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_css_alter().
 */
function YOURTHEME_css_alter(&$css) {
  // Remove stylesheets not required
  unset($css['sites/default/themes/YOURTHEME/css/STYLESHEET.css']);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 */
function YOURTHEME_js_alter(&$js) {
  // Remove scripts not required
  unset($js['sites/default/themes/YOURTHEME/js/SCRIPT.js']);
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks...I swear I tried this earlier but it didn't work...then again I tried unsetting the whole object.

Ideally I need to remove all the module CSS such as node.css, user.css, etc

Comment: that works if I specify individually which elements needs to be dropped. Are they the same set of core files added though? I would rather delete everything except what I have listed in them theme.info file...

Lastly, Drupal renders the styles as @imports -- I would prefer <link> so maybe an override of the entire markup would make sense?!?

Answer (score 0):

You would like to check [Mothership](https://drupal.org/project/mothership) theme, which does exactly what you want.